# Run script returned from jQuery $.get

Tags: jquery, get

I have a link that calls a jQuery `.get()` function that returns more jQuery script that is to be appended to the calling container. The data is being returned, but is not being executed, just simply printed to the page.

The Call:

```
$('<a/>').attr('href', "#").addClass('link-button').html("Add New").on('click', function () {
    Loader.Show(); 
    $.get("webservice.php", {news: "addnew"}, function (data) {$("#page").empty().append(data);});
    return false;
});
```

The data returned:

```
$('<form/>').attr('action', "webservice.php").attr('method', "post").append(
    $('<input/>').attr('type', "hidden").attr('name', "news").val("add"),
    $('<p/>').append(
        "Title:",
        $('<input/>').attr('type', "text").attr('name', "title").attr('data-required', "true").on('focusout', function () {
            if($(this).val() == "") {$(this).addClass('required');} else {$(this).removeClass('required');}
        })
    ),
    $('<p/>').append(
        "Text:",
        $('<input/>').attr('type', "text").attr('name', "text").attr('data-required', "true").addClass('paragraph').on('focusout', function () {
            if($(this).val() == "") {$(this).addClass('required');} else {$(this).removeClass('required');}
        })
    ),
    $('<p/>').append(
        $('<input/>').attr('type', "submit").val("Post"),
        $('<span/>').addClass('availabletext')
    )
).on('submit', function () {
    Loader.Show("Posting...");
    $(this).find('[type=submit]').attr('disabled', "disabled");
    var gtg = true;
    $(this).find('[data-required=true]').each(function () {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass('required');
            gtg = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('required');
        }
    });
    if($(this).find('[data-type=vote]').val() == "No" && $(this).find('[data-type=comment]').val() == "") {
        $(this).find('[data-type=comment]').addClass('required');
        gtg = false;
    } else {
        $(this).find('[data-type=comment]').removeClass('required');
    }
    if(gtg) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $(this).find('[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled', "disabled");
        Loader.Hide();
        return false;
    }
}).ajaxForm({success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $(this).parent().empty().append(data);
}, error: function () {
    $(this).append("Server timeout, please try again...");
    $("#submit-button").removeAttr('disabled');
    Loader.Hide();
}});
```

The problem is that the code returned is literally being printed to the page instead being processed and executed. Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like so:

```
jQuery.getScript('webservice.php?news=addnew', function() {
    console.log('script loaded!');
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript

Comment: That may help, however I am not having a problem getting the script back from the page. It's getting the page to process the incoming script. Basically I'm trying to get `function (data) { $("#page").empty().append(data); }` to work. And since `$("#page").append($('<a/>'));` works I am wondering why the former doesn't work, since it is essentially doing the exact same thing...

Comment: jQuery.getScript() should process the script as you are asking, have you tried it? Other solutions involve 1) creating a script element, setting the src to the appropriate url and appending to the head of the document, or 2) wrapping the incoming code in a script tag like so `"<scri"+"pt>" + data + "</script>"`. But since you are using jQuery, getScript is the right option for you.